# A fast, general way to create a matrix of a sequence of values in Stata

Tags: stata

Say I want a vector of 0:10

I know I can do

```
matrix x = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

but is there more a general way to do this? say if wanted to create a matrix of 0:100, or 27:50, or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

figured it out, you have to create the vector in mata, and then return it to stata:

```
mata: x = range(0,10,1)
mata: st_matrix("x", x)
```

or just

```
mata: st_matrix("x", range(0,10,1))
```

Comment: Compare also `mata : st_matrix("bar", (0::100))` and  `mata : st_matrix("bar", (0..100))`.

Comment: no, I've just benefited massively from your answers here and statalist

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very appealing but it also works:

```
numlist "0/100"
local numlist `r(numlist)'
local numlist : subinstr local numlist " " ",", all
matrix foo = (`numlist')
```